# Clean up data in CSV without Pandas

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to plot a line chart with the following data (csv format) as attached.

1. I want to replace and consolidate all the quarter into a year
   For example: 1990-Q1, 1990-Q2, 1990-Q3, 1990-Q4 into 1990.
2. Based on the year, I would like to consolidate the indexes e.g. all the 4 indexes in the year.
3. I want to filter the years to solely 2007 - 2017. As the dataset had years/quarters from 1990 to 2019.

How do I do that without using Pandas?

I had added in my partial code but seemed like I might be on the wrong direction. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Please do not paste your code and data sample as an image but rather as text.

Comment: And why exactly don't you want to use Pandas?

Comment: oh sorry my first time using this. it was an assignment and we were told not to use Pandas. But I tried to google all the information, seemed like majority uses df from pandas.

Comment: Ok. And again: Post your code and data sample as **raw text** in your posting so that others can replicate your problem.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestions and guidance. I just feel that I'm heading in the wrong directions for getting the data cleaning part.

Comment: You´re welcome. And a data sample is neccesary/helpful to let others examine the problem you face. You can paste inline or e.g. to PasteBin.

Comment: I had problems accessing to Pastebin due to the security issues. May I know how to paste inline? I had attached the link to the csv file, does it work out that way?

Comment: Sure! That is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you happy with `data`, that you get from `genfromtxt`?  A structured array like that should be nearly as useful for this as a pandas DataFrame.  It has the same info.

Looking that the `.png`, it looks like the quarters are in consecutive order, without gaps.  If so.

```
data1 = data.reshape(-1,4)
```

should give a (n,4) array, with one year per row.

```
data1['index'].sum(axis=1)
```

should be the sum of index values for each year.  (or you might want `mean`).

You can pick a range of years from `data1` with `data1[n:m]`, where you choose the range by counting/calculating or even parsing the year string.

You could stick with splitting `x` on 'year' and 'quarter', and so on, but I think the the reshape saves a lot of work.

Comment: It had the following error: (Am I missing out on any steps?)

    data1 = data.reshape(-1,4)

    ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 119 into shape (4)

Comment: the dataset is missing 1 quarter, the current one.

Comment: that's the dataset given in the system, what could I do in this scenario?